# Unbreakable cventry in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to update my CV and I hit a limitation. I use `moderncv` and have been quite satisfied with it so far. But now that my experience section has grown beyond a presumed limit it yields an odd result. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}                   

\firstname{Jack}\familyname{Ceevee}
\address{876A Defect Lane}{San Francisco, California} 
\mobile{+1-615-555-1212}\email{j.ceevee@mail.com}        

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Summary}
\cvline{}{\lipsum[1]}

\section{Technical Skills}
\cvline{A great skill}{\lipsum[2]}

\section{Experience}
\cventry{2000--present}{Space occupier}{freelance}{San Francisco}{}{%
\lipsum[3-5]}

\end{document}
```

The odd thing is that the last section is not broken in two, rather it is moved to a new page leaving about 1/3rd of page 1 empty. I wonder if it is caused by the minipage environment `moderncv` uses for *cventry* (at least I think it does) or maybe something else. Regardless, I'm looking for a way to fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah I think your best bet is to find a different way of describing the information outside of a `cventry`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pity. No way. Latest version of `moderncv` uses `tabular` and `minipage` internally, and old version uses `longtable`. You can't break a tabular line or box.

It is possible to reimplement `moderncv` with lists, but not easy. You'd better avoid such long item or use another template.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to have to find some other way. The search begins...

Comment: Heisenb0rg, have you found any other way?